# Dilation Gradient w/ different ROI's (blob optimization) OPENCV

Tags: c++, opencv, blob, gradient, roi

I'm working on a dilation problem in c++ with opencv. I've captured videoframes of a car park and in order to obtain the best blobs I came up with this.

1. Erosion (5x5 kernel rectangular), 3 iterations
2. Dilation GRADIENT (think of it like a color gradient along the y-axis)

So what did I do to get this working? First I needed to know 2 points (x,y) and 2 good dilate kernelsizes at those points. With this information one can inter and extrapolate those values over the whole image. So I calculated ROI's (size and dilation kernelsize) from those parameters. So each ROI has its own predefined kernelsize used for dilation. Note that there isn't any space between two consecutive ROI's (opencv rectangles). Everything is working fine, but **there are two side effects**:

1. Buldges on the sides of the blobs. The black line is de border of the ROI! 
   [buldges picture](http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/8096/buldges.png)
2. Blobs which are 'cut off' from the main blob. These aren't actually cut off but the ROI under the one of the blob above dilates (gets pixel information from the above ROI, I think) into blobs who are seperated. It should be one massive blob. [blob who shoudn't be there picture](http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/6261/blobleft.png)

I've tried everything on changing the ROI sizes and left some space between them but the disadvantage is that the blob between 2 seperated ROI's is not dilated.

So my questions are:

1. What causes those side effects exactly?
2. What do I have to do to make them go away?

EDIT

So I found my solution: when you call the opencv dilate function, one needs to be sure if the same cv::Mat can be used as destination image. If not you'll be using parts of the original and new image. So all I had to do was including a destination cv::Mat.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your first question (What causes those side effects for sure), but to make them go away, you can do some variant of the following, assuming the ROI parameters are discrete and not continuous (as seems to be the case).

You can compute the dilation for the entire image using every possible kernel size.  Then, after all of those binary images are computed, you can combine them together taking the correct samples from the correct image to get the desired output image.  This absolutely will waste a good deal of time, but it should work with no artifacts.

Once you've confirmed that the results you've gotten above (which are pretty much guaranteed to be of as-good-as-possible quality) you can start trying to optimize.  One thing I'd try is expanding each of the ROI sizes for computing the dilation by the size of the kernel size.  This might get around artifacts that can arise from strange boundary conditions.

This leads to my guess as to what causes the artifacts in the first place:  Whenever you take a finite image and run a convolution (or morphological operator) you need to choose what you'll do with the edge pixels.  Normally, accessing the pixel at (-4, -1) is meaningless, but to perform the operator you'll have to if your kernel overlaps with it.  If OpenCV is doing this edge padding for your subregions, it very easily could give you the artifacts you're seeing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response, if I hadn't found my solution this would be my last resort.